# Mule ESB integration in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mule

I am building an application using `AngularJS`. There is one file upload module in my application where users can upload multiple files at a time. I was told to use `Mule ESB` to do this module. How can I integrate Mule ESB to my AngularJS application?. Is there any good tutorials which explains my query?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expose an HTTP inbound endpoint and have your AngularJS application HTTP POST the data to it. Beware of potential [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) issues if you serve your AngularJS app from a different scheme/domain as where Mule is running.